# ExpressJS: response ignored following POST

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm attempting to make my first REST API with NodeJS, Express, and Mongo. I've got most of the code working -- I can get data from the database using a GET and write to it using a POST. However, for some reason, the response parameter in the POST callback seems to be ignored completely. I've tried calling res.render([a working template]), res.end(), res.send(), etc., and the code just seems to skip past the response like it's not there. No error, just doesn't do anything. I also tried changing the POST URI to something else, like /api/projectsave, in case the routes were somehow interfering with each other, but that didn't help.

**EDIT:** The Success callback in the JQuery code does get run if I switch to res.json(). (Thanks to @Molda for that.) However, the original question still stands, as the response object doesn't render anything with res.render(). Why is that?

Here's the relevant code (in my API controller):

```
app.get('/api/project/:id', function(req, res) {
    Project.find({id: req.params.id}, function(err, projects) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (projects.length > 0) {
            res.json(projects);
        } else {
            res.render('form');
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api/project', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index'); // Here's the line that doesn't do anything.
    console.log("Body: " + util.inspect(req.body, false, null)); // This line gets run.
    var item = Project(req.body);
    item.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err; // And this save to the db works fine.
        console.log('Project saved with id ' + req.body.id + '.');
        res.render('index'); // Doesn't work down here, either.
    })
});

app.get('/api/project', function(req, res) {
    res.render('form');
});
```

and the form (it's a Jade template, but here's the rendered HTML):

```
<form id="form" name="add-project" method="POST" action="/api/project">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="id">ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc">
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Project">
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
       var o = {};
       var a = this.serializeArray();
       $.each(a, function() {
           if (o[this.name]) {
               if (!o[this.name].push) {
                   o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
               }
               o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
           } else {
               o[this.name] = this.value || '';
           }
       });
       return o;
    };
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/api/project', 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function(data) {
                // This callback does successfully run
                alert("Success: " + data);
            },
            failure: function(err) {
                alert("Failed: " + err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try res.json({status:'ok'}); ?  your ajax expects data type json so it might ignore response if it's not json

Comment: I gave it a shot, but didn't help.

Comment: Can you show me jsonParser variable ?

Comment: Sure, it's just using the body-parser package:

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var util = require('util');

    var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

Comment: @Molda - Your response did help, in that the jQuery callback gets run if I switch to res.json(). However, why does res.render() not do anything? Is it up to the client to redirect following a POST?

Comment: @user2684124 Try to remove **dataType: 'json',** and you should see that res.render actualy works. I think jQuery.ajax expects json and since it's not, it simply won't give you any data but i'm not sure tho.

Comment: Can you add console.log(data) in success callback in jQuery. I think render method is executed, but you have different expectations

Comment: @Molda - OK, it looks like your solution did work, but the res.render() is sending back the rendered HTML as a string rather than actually rendering the page, which, you're right, is not what I was expecting.

Comment: If you want to render another page after posting data then why are you using ajax? If you want to render the html return from server then use jquery to append it to document. But then you need res.render to render html without layout. If i remember correctly you need res.render('your-view',{layout:false});

Comment: @Molda, OK, good point. I switched the form back to be a normal submit (sans ajax) and the page renders as I expected when I call res.render(). I just didn't realize that the browser would handle the response in the way it does when using an ajax call, but it makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it up to the client to redirect following a POST?

Yes, it is.

Acccording to comments, you are getting a proper rendered page from your endpoint. And this is a correct behaviour. You just need to insert response html somewhere on a page.